# An error occurred while using the classLoader related configuration

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

My flink application run in yarn clusters in per-job mode. In order to enhance the functionality of the lookup functions, I override some functions in the official lib table-planner_2.12 and table-runtime. I use the configuration 'classloader.parent-first-patterns.default' and 'yarn.classpath.include-user-jar' to avoid replace the jars in the Flink /lib folder. But inconsistent behavior occurred at different stages of program execution. The two configurations can work correctly in jobManager and taskManager, but they have no effect in the client which is work to generate streamGraph.

I print the classLoader when the user's main function run, it is correctly 'ChildFirstClassLoader'. But when it call the function 'tpChangelogStream' and then the planner work, the classLoader load the class in the official table-planner_2.12 jar instead of the same name in user jar.

What should I do to make the configurations take effect in all stages of flink application execution?